# Какого рода слово "Каноэ–двойка"?

Tags: род

Какого рода слово "Каноэ–двойка"?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Какого рода слово "Каноэ–двойка"?

**Русский орфографический словарь** говорит, что женского.

См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8D%E2%80%93%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0&all=x:

> **каноэ-двойка**, -и, *р. мн.* -двоек, ***ж***.

Answer (score 2):

[Вопрос № 272363](https://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE&start=30)
Какого рода слово каноэ-двойка?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Это существительное женского рода. См.: Русский орфографический словарь РАН / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина, О. Е. Ивановой. – 4-е изд., испр. и доп. – М., 2012.

В орфографическом словаре русского языка (2006):
[каноэ-одиночка](https://orthographic.academic.ru/25355/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8D), (1 ж), Р. каноэ-одиночки;
[каноэ-двойка](https://orthographic.academic.ru/25353/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%8D-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0), (1 ж), Р. каноэ-двойки.

На дистанции 500 метров золото взяла российская каноэ-двойка...
Каноэ-четверка в составе (…) отлично стартовала в заезде и лидировала...

Answer (score 0):

> Род сложных имён существительных, пишущихся через  дефис, обычно
>   определяется:
>
> 1) по первой части, если изменяются обе части: моё кресло-кровать —
>   моего кресла-кровати (ср.р.), новый самолёт-амфибия — нового
>   самолёта-амфибии (м.р.);
>
> 2) по второй части, если первая не изменяется: сверкающая жар-птица —
>   сверкающую жар-птицу (ж.р.), огромная меч-рыба — огромной меч-рыбы
>   (ж.р.).
>
> В некоторых случаях род не определяется, так как сложное слово
>   употребляется только во множественном числе: сказочные
>   сапоги-скороходы — сказочных сапог-скороходов (мн.ч.)-

[Отсюда.](http://lingvotech.com/roddefis)

Слово "каноэ", конечно, не будет склоняться, но только потому, что это слово - заимствованное, заканчивающееся на -э, и его невозможно склонять. Но оно - смысловое в данной паре, поэтому род следует определять по нему. Моё мнение - средний род.

Answer (score 0):

Мы определяем род сложного существительного **по словарю**, проверяем его по реальным текстам. Итак, **каноэ-двойка — это существительное ж. рода.**

Но не менее интересно понять, **почему сделан такой выбор.**

Здесь возможны два решения: **грамматическое и смысловое.**

***Каноэ*** — несклоняемое существительное среднего рода. В сложном слове *каноэ-двойка* ***каноэ*** — определяемое слово, а двойка — это приложение.

**При смысловом решении** род сложного существительного определяется по главному слову, а здесь таким словом является каноэ (средний род).

**При грамматическом решении** смысловые отношения не учитываются, здесь важна форма:  **несклоняемое существительное на первом месте, а склоняемое на втором** (не важно, что является определяемым словом, а что приложением). Например: *царь-колокол, царь-пушка, горе-охотник, жар-птица.*

Для существительного "каноэ-двойка" использовано именно грамматическое решение, **ж.род определен по второму склоняемому слову.**

**А с точки зрения смысла** здесь может дополнительно учитываться,  что  каноэ — это лодка (ж.р.).

Comment: О последней фразе. Заменить на "лодку" и выставить род по ней - спорный способ, поскольку каноэ - еще и челн, а также, конечно, плавсредство.

Comment: ВЫСТАВИТЬ род - это, вероятно,  определить род? (Стилевую характеристику сочетания определить затрудняюсь). Но род определяется по словарю, а не по МНЕНИЮ кого-либо.  С другой стороны, выбор хотелось бы обосновать, что я и делаю в своем ответе. Что касается названия каноэ-двойка, то оно применяется  к  спортивным лодкам (см. словарь),  поэтому именно лодка используется здесь в качестве родового слова.